# background image not appear in IE but appears in firefox

Tags: css

my background images appear in chrome and firefox, but not in IE 8.
my site is www.burodsin.com the first homepage with the logo.

in css background, i added

```
.bclass:link {
background-image: url('images/buroimagenew.jpg');
position: absolute;
width: 40px;
height: 97px;
display: block;
z-index:12;
 }
```

Comment: Only thing i see in the link is BLACK!!!!!!

Comment: The code in the question and on the page is different.

Answer (score 3):

The problem on your page is that you are defining `repeat` properties `no-repeat` on `background-image`, like this

```
background-image: url('images/buroimagenew.jpg') no-repeat; 
                                                /* ^ This is NOT a background-image accepted value */
```

Either separate the properties like

```
background-image: url('images/buroimagenew.jpg'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Or write the **correct** shorthand rule.

```
background: url('images/buroimagenew.jpg') no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following are different background properties are:

`background`

`background-image`

`background-repeat`

`background-color`

`background-clip`

`background-attachment`

`background-origin`

`background-position`

So separate as:

`background-image: url('urlofyourimage.jpg');`

`background-repeat: no-repeat;`